# Is DriverPack Solution trustworthy?

Tags: windows, drivers, malware, bloatware

Is [DriverPackSolution](http://drp.su/) trustworthy?

I had used it to install my laptop drivers a year ago. It worked and I didn't care whether it was trustworthy or not, until now.

It claims to install *all* drivers of *any* Windows computer automatically without hassle. It is a big download and is capable of installing drivers offline. Also, it's site shows that it's licenced under GNU GPL. It has recently gotten very popular.

I've read some bad comments about it on many sites. But many seem to be happy with it. However, I'm still a bit suspicious about whether I should keep using it.

Comment: I would not install it.  Windows Update installs all required drivers automatically.  Furthermore it takes very little effort to install any drivers not installed yourself.  This question isn't on topic since your asking our opinion of the website.

Comment: There is NO WAY a pack can have EVERY possible driver to install ALL required drivers for ANY computer

Comment: I too am anti-this.

Comment: It also claims Windows 8.1 RTM support which isn't out yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have some experience with this program, I used to work at a local repair shop that used this for installing nearly all of their drivers. The program does what it advertises very well, it will install a ton of drivers for you and the program is very simple to use.

I've run the thing through a few different AV / Virus Removal programs and it has turned up clean, but that doesn't necessarily mean it is safe. I have noticed that it changes your OEMINFO properties to advertise itself further, which when working on a client or customers computer, is a very bad thing. For example, if you go to My Computer -> Properties, it will have changed the 'Manufactured and Supported by' tags in Windows Xp, Vista, and 7.

From my experience, it works well, but I don't recommend using it. Like some of the other answers here have said, it requires minimal effort to find and install drivers from a more legitimate source (Manufacturer Website). Also, I believe it is of Russian origin and impossible to find support for.

Tl;dr - It works well for installing drivers., but you probably shouldn't use it. Alters system information without prompting, and that usually isn't a good sign.

Comment: I've recently tested Driverpack Solution 15.7 on my PC. It seems to install adware to the internet browser of the PC. Beware!

Comment: Don't use it, I used it on a fresh installed windows 7 computer, I made a malware scan with malwarebytes anti malware and guess what? 90 Malware found, I was able to reproduce this on another computer where I previously made a malware scan and had 0 results, but after installing this software I had 90 results.

Comment: I've been using it for a long time ago many times in different machines, all of them was really bad experience, even if it install your driver successfully, you'll have issues with that driver